# How to parse a function into another function in scheme

Tags: scheme, guile

I am trying to create a function that takes another function as a parameter and calls the functions in a loop.

The code below should get the function and the number of times the loop should execute:

```
(define (forLoop loopBody reps)
    (let
        (
         (fun (car loopBody))
         (str (cdr loopBody))
        )
       (cond
          ((eval (= reps 0) (interaction-environment)) "")
          (else (cons str (forLoop '(fun str) (- reps 1))))
       )
    )
)
```

The code below is how i am calling the function

```
(define (printermsg)
  (display msg)
 )
(forLoop '(printer "text ") 4)
```

The expected output for the above code:

```
text text text text
```

Comment: You should not format and indent your code opening and closing parentheses `()` in a line by themselves, they're not brackets `{}` you know :) . That's not the usual style to do it, a good IDE will help you to balance your parentheses. See my answer for the recommended way to format Scheme code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- The way you pass the `loopBody` parameter to your function is incorrect, a list of symbols will not work: you want to pass along a list with the actual *function* and its argument.
- You are not obtaining the second element in the list, `cdr` won't work because it returns the rest of the list, you need to use `cadr` instead.
- Avoid using `eval`, it's not necessary at all for what you want, and in general is a bad idea.
- Why are you building a list? `cons` is not required here.
- When calling the recursion, you are again passing a list of symbols instead of the proper argument.
- You're not actually *calling* the function!

This should work:

```
(define (forLoop loopBody reps)
  (let ((fun (car  loopBody))
        (str (cadr loopBody)))
    (cond
      ((= reps 0) (void)) ; don't do anything when the loop is done
      (else
       (fun str) ; actually call the function!
       (forLoop loopBody (- reps 1))))))

(define (printer msg)
  (display msg))

(forLoop (list printer "text ") 4) ; see how to build the loop body
=> text text text text
```